# How to use sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance for clustering algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, cluster-analysis, feature-extraction

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=4,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_redundant=0,
                           n_repeated=0,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

km = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(X)

result = permutation_importance(km, X, y, scoring='homogeneity_score', n_repeats=10, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
result
```

In the real problem, I don't have y (true label), I tried to do `y=None` to make it as an unsupervised learning. But it does not work. I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-81045ae9cb66> in <module>()
----> 1 result = permutation_importance(km, X, y=None, scoring='homogeneity_score', n_repeats=10, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster/_supervised.py in check_clusterings(labels_true, labels_pred)
     53     if labels_true.ndim != 1:
     54         raise ValueError(
---> 55             "labels_true must be 1D: shape is %r" % (labels_true.shape,))
     56     if labels_pred.ndim != 1:
     57         raise ValueError(

ValueError: labels_true must be 1D: shape is ()
```

Do anyone know how to implement without true label?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is trivial to prove that k-means is invariant to a permutation of features... Because the sum is permutation invariant.

If you still want to experiment, try using an array of 0s as y maybe?